# Disabling textbox upon selecting specific value in drop down of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a gridview and each row has Drop down list,Containing VALID (1), INVALID (0)

i want if user select Invalid from drop down then it should disable text box given in form, txtComplainant.

i tried putting TxtboxComplainant.Visible = false; upon SelectedIndexChange Event but doesn't work.

Code:

```
protected void ddlIsComplaint_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(row.RowIndex);
        //lblSelectionMessage.InnerText = RowIndex.ToString();

        foreach(GridViewRow rw in GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows)
        {
            if(rw.RowIndex != RowIndex)
            {
                rw.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
            if (ddl.SelectedValue == "0") 
            {
                txtComplainant.Visible = false;
            }
     }
```

Aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"  Width="650px" OnRowDataBound="GridViewSmsComplaints_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
               <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sms ID" DataField="ID" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
                    <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Incoming No" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Complaint" DataField="Message" >   
                     <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Valid?">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint"  runat="server" />--%>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsComplaint" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIsComplaint_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Invalid" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Valid" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>

                     </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView> 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtComplainant" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: yes, it is calling Selected indexChanged, doing perfect work but it isn't disabling textbox but when i put disabling code elsewhere then it works

Comment: I don't see txtComplainant defined in your html code

Comment: There a very very better and simple way and better performance if using jQuery, I can provide this answer for you if you don't have problem with jQuery. Also i can't see `txtComplainant` in your ASPX code?

Comment: i just omitted that intentionally, it has txtComplainant

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not finding the control..

This part

```
if (ddl.SelectedValue == "0") 
{
   txtComplainant.Visible = false;
}
```

should be in the foreach I would think.. like this..

```
foreach(GridViewRow rw in GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows)
{
   TextBox txtComplainant = ((TextBox)rw.FindControl("txtComplainant"));//added this line to find the control.

    if(rw.RowIndex != RowIndex)
    {
       rw.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (ddl.SelectedValue == "0") 
    {
       txtComplainant.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

If this does not give you the results you desire, you can try this as well..

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
TextBox txtComplainant = ((TextBox)rw.FindControl("txtComplainant"));

if (ddl.SelectedValue == "0") 
{
  txtComplainant.Visible = false;
}
```

You will want to put this underneath your foreach loop. This should disable the control within the row that the drop down was changed on.

EDIT: I didn't realize it was outside the grid. I have tested what you have from you question and it seems to work.

This is how I tested it.

```
    protected void ddlTestDrop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

        if (ddl.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            tbTestBox.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (ddl.SelectedValue == "0")
        {
            tbTestBox.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I was able to click back and forth between 1 and 0 to make it visible and then invisible. I would suggest removing the following..

```
int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(row.RowIndex);
//lblSelectionMessage.InnerText = RowIndex.ToString();

foreach(GridViewRow rw in GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows)
{
   if(rw.RowIndex != RowIndex)
   {
      rw.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: sir, txtComplainanti outside gridview,

Comment: ah, thought that it was within the gridview

Comment: help in this matter sir

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Your code seems to be correct for the most part. I have suggested to remove/comment out the foreach to see if that is the problem area.

Comment: yes Humpry sir, it fixed but i need foreach, its must

i put code outside foreach and it was not working again